# Extract Wordpress WYSIWYG Editor for use in another project

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I'm looking to start on a new project, and I need an online text editor.

I really like what Wordpress does with its modification of TinyMCE. Since Wordpress is Open Source... I was wondering if we are allowed to extract its editor? Is it even possible without weeks worth of work? Has anyone here done it before or is able to give me some tips on how to do it?

Or, does anyone have any suggestions for an editor that has image/file upload support AND custom CSS in the editor? I've looked at TinyMCE and it'd be great except no image upload feature...

Thank so much in advance.